# Mysql: update attribute if and only if other attribute was changed

Tags: python, mysql

On UPDATE query I would like to change need_parse attribute if url attribute was changed.
need_parse depends on url value.

How can I achieve this on MySQL & Python?

Comment: On update, do you want to change need_parse attribute, only if url attribute is changed, Otherwise do not execute the update query, Is it what you want? Say, update query is to change the need_parse attribute, then you want if that update also involves change in url attribute. If yes, then execute the update query on need_parse attribute else not? Is it what you want? Or something else?

Comment: I always want to perform the update but i want to update need_parse attribute if and only if url attribute was changed.
all other attribute will be updated even if their values did not change.

Comment: Solution: use trigger  - see [reference ][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296313/mysql-trigger-after-update-only-if-row-has-changed?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need something like:

```
UPDATE tbl
SET need_parse = CASE WHEN url = <input url> THEN need_parse ELSE <value to change to> END
```

Comment: I created a trigger for such thing.
This was my reference:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296313/mysql-trigger-after-update-only-if-row-has-changed?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following trigger to put check on updates. It will do what you require

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE
    TRIGGER `test`.`update_check` BEFORE UPDATE
    ON `db_name`.`table_name`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF (new.`url` = old.`url`)
    THEN SET new.`need_parse` = old.`need_parse`;
    END IF;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Hope it helps...