# how to update mysql table automatically?

Tags: mysql

Here is my problem:

```
    USER TABLE

id  uploader_name   email
1   abhijit         xxx@email.com
2   rahul           abc@email.com


    UPLOAD TABLE

ID  USER_ID     IMAGE_URL
1   1           UPLOAD/XXX.JPG
2   1           UPLOAD/ABC.JPG
3   2           UPLOAD/CD.JPG
```

How to connect `USER_ID` in table `UPLOAD TABLE` with `id` in table `USERS TABLE`? So, the `USER_ID` field automatically update.
Now my problem is how to add data in `USER_ID` in table `UPLOAD TABLE`. I am able to add data in every field except `USER_ID`.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), please.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can add a trigger to update the user_id field of upload table. Please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296313/mysql-trigger-after-update-only-if-row-has-changed) which will help you to know about triggers and how to update the field automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is like:
You first add contents to your UPLOAD table, without knowing USER_ID.
And, then, you are attempting to patch the USER_ID once you know it.
But by that time, the data has been already inserted to the database.

Probable answer:
After each insert, you can call **LAST_INSERT_ID()** to get your auto_increment value of latest inserted table. Use this ID to later patch(UPDATE) the UPLOAD table with this user_id.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

Otherwise if the scene is:
You want to update the IDs of user_id if USER table is modified.
In this case, please use innodb table with foreign key constraints that makes sure that you keep the proper relationships. Further, use **ON UPDATE CASCADE** to bring your changes in IDs to the other table.

Anyway, please further explain the problem.