# Trigger only if Table if updated

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I want to trigger the table after update only if any change is made in the table.

[I tried this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296313/mysql-trigger-after-update-only-if-row-has-changed)

but it is giving error.
My code is

`CREATE TRIGGER Trans_SubCategory_update AFTER UPDATE ON Trans_SubCategory
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF NEW.ts <> OLD.ts THEN

           INSERT  INTO Sync_activities (table_name,table_id,admin_id,action) 
                 VALUES('Trans_SubCategory',New.id,New.admin_id,'update');
        END IF;
  END;`

It is giving error

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6 .

But if I use

`CREATE TRIGGER Trans_SubCategory_update AFTER UPDATE ON Trans_SubCategory
     FOR EACH ROW 
     INSERT  INTO Sync_activities (table_name,table_id,admin_id,action) 
                 VALUES('Trans_SubCategory',New.id,New.admin_id,'update');`

I add the trigger but triggers even if no change is made in table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is - you're forgetting to set proper delimiter. Your first syntax contains multiple operators inside trigger - and they need to be delimited by `;` - but you're not changing global delimiter - thus, MySQL treats that as syntax end - and, therefore, that's an error (because trigger isn't completed, obviously).

Your second syntax is executed completely since it has only one operator (and that stands for trigger end as well) - you've not enclosed it by `BEGIN..END`

To fix the issue, just do:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER Trans_SubCategory_update AFTER UPDATE ON Trans_SubCategory 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
  IF NEW.ts != OLD.ts THEN
    INSERT INTO Sync_activities (table_name,table_id,admin_id,action) VALUES ('Trans_SubCategory', NEW.id, NEW.admin_id,'update');
  END IF; 
END;//
DELIMITER ;
```