# Mysql - Create trigger to insert a new row based on a row inserted in another table

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

Hi I have two tables called `users` and `userrewards`. When a new row gets inserted into the users table, I want to take the `userid` and create a new row in the userrewards table, only if the `usertype` is "premium". In the userrewards table I just need to insert the userid - the rest of the fields are set to default values until the user makes changes themselves. How can I do this via a trigger?

Comment: check https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an "after instert" trigger on user: that's the table you're watching. Now, if I guessed your column names correctly, the sql for creating the trigger should look like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER user_ai AFTER INSERT ON user 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF new.usertype = 'premium' THEN
        INSERT INTO userrewards (user_id) VALUES new.id;
    END IF;
END;
```

Another example of a trigger with if statements and :old / :new values can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296313/mysql-trigger-after-update-only-if-row-has-changed). MySQL documentatation for create trigger [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html). MySQL documentation for the if-syntax [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html).

Comment: MySQL does not use the colon before NEW and OLD. I think that's Oracle syntax.

Comment: Thanks, @BillKarwin. You're right: I confused MySQL with Oracle.