# Update TimeStamp on Single Column Update

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I have one table called `number_list` which have columns like:

`id, name, number, server, status, last_act, user_id, created_at, disable, notify,fcm`

I want update `last_act` when there any changes in `status` column only. Currently its updating `last_act` whenever any changes in any column.
Let me know if its possible with MySQL. Thanks

Comment: Yes it is possible; have you tried resolving this yourself first or researched it?

Comment: what are the possible values for status? is the update query will work on the basis on id column?what you have tried ? have you tried trigger?

Comment: status value is 0 or 1. Thanks

Comment: Create `ON UPDATE` trigger where you could check whenever the status has been changed. More here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296313/mysql-trigger-after-update-only-if-row-has-changed

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Setting up a trigger like the following should accomplish what you have asked.

```
DELIMITER $$
        CREATE TRIGGER number_list_update_trigger 
        BEFORE UPDATE 
        ON number_list
        FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
          if (NEW.status = OLD.status) THEN 
             set NEW.last_act = OLD.last_act;
          END IF;
        END $$
  DELIMITER ;
```