# Is it possible to insert a row but only if a value has changed?

Tags: mysql

I've already read this:

[How do I insert into a database only if a value has changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781501/how-do-i-insert-into-a-database-only-if-a-value-has-changed)

So my question is very close, but it's not exaclty the same.

I have a table with 4 "main" columns (ie I have those 4 same columns on all my tables):

- `id` - int - autoinc
- `id_origin` - int - id when the first record was created
- `date_v_start` - datetime - start date of validity of the record
- `date_v_end` - datetime - end of validity of the record (if `NULL` it's the current 'valid' record)

Here are some other fields specific to this table:
- `summary` - text
- `detail` - text

knowing this, when I have something that has been changed into that table, here's what I do:

- I update `date_v_end` of the current record to "now()"
- I insert a new record, with `date_v_start` = `date_v_end` of the previous, `id_origin` = the same of the previous, - `date_v_end` = `NULL` and (of course) the new values of `summary` and `detail`.

My problem is that if the values of `summary` and `detail` haven't changed I don't want to insert that new record, it's a waste of time, and hard drive space.

Is there a way to do (in one shot if possible) something like:

"if `summary<>'a value' or detail<>'another value' then update this record and insert this new one`"

?

So, the difference between my question and the link I've provided above is:
- there are more than one field to compare
- there are two requests
- i'd like to make it in one request if possible.

Comment: You can either write the logic in your app, use a stored procedure, or use a trigger. Which of these would be OK?

Comment: maybe use a trigger, or use a stored procedure. I'd like to be compatible if possible with both `mysql` and `postgresql`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I did it in one "php query" = one string with commas in the middle (it's very time consuming, but I'll change it one day if my webserver can't handle it anymore):

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE id=:id;
ALTER TABLE tmp drop ID;
INSERT INTO table
SELECT 0,tmp.* FROM tmp;
DROP TABLE tmp:
UPDATE table
SET date_v_fin=NOW()
WHERE id=LAST_INSERT_ID();
```